# AWS Beanstalk: cannot load such file -- acl9/controller_extensions (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I deploy app to AWS Beanstalk I'm getting this error:

```
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require':
cannot load such file -- acl9/controller_extensions (LoadError)
```

is it a compatibility problem?
Locally everything works. Creating new environment didn't help and I'm getting the same error. Thank you very much!

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'puma'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.11'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more:                https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the     background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]

gem "paranoia", "~> 2.0"

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem "byebug"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end

gem 'roo', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'roo-xls'

gem 'render_anywhere', :require => false

gem 'libv8'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails" #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"

gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.5.0'

gem 'devise'

gem 'acl9', '~> 2.0'

gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap'

gem 'i18n_generators'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'

#gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'date_picker'

gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    acl9 (2.1.1)
      rails (~> 4.0)
    actionmailer (4.1.11)
      actionpack (= 4.1.11)
      actionview (= 4.1.11)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.11)
      actionview (= 4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionview (4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    activemodel (4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.11)
      activemodel (= 4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (0.9.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (6.0.2)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.9.1.1)
    commonjs (0.2.7)
    date_picker (0.0.8)
      rails (>= 4.0.3)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.5.4)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    domain_name (0.5.25)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    font-awesome-sass (4.5.0)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    hike (1.2.3)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    i18n_generators (2.0.0)
      mechanize
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    jbuilder (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-turbolinks (2.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1.0)
      turbolinks
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    less (2.6.0)
      commonjs (~> 0.2.7)
    less-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      less (~> 2.6.0)
      sprockets (> 2, < 4)
      tilt
    libv8 (3.16.14.11)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mechanize (2.7.4)
      domain_name (~> 0.5, >= 0.5.1)
      http-cookie (~> 1.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.17.2, < 3)
      net-http-digest_auth (~> 1.1, >= 1.1.1)
      net-http-persistent (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.2)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      ntlm-http (~> 0.1, >= 0.1.1)
      webrobots (>= 0.0.9, < 0.2)
    mime-types (2.6.2)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (5.8.0)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    mysql2 (0.3.18)
    net-http-digest_auth (1.4)
    net-http-persistent (2.9.4)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    ntlm-http (0.1.1)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paranoia (2.1.3)
      activerecord (~> 4.0)
    puma (2.16.0)
    rack (1.5.5)
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.11)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.11)
      actionpack (= 4.1.11)
      actionview (= 4.1.11)
      activemodel (= 4.1.11)
      activerecord (= 4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.11)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails-jquery-autocomplete (1.0.3)
      rails (>= 3.2)
    railties (4.1.11)
      actionpack (= 4.1.11)
      activesupport (= 4.1.11)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
    ref (2.0.0)
    render_anywhere (0.0.12)
      rails (>= 3.0.7)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    roo (2.1.1)
      nokogiri (~> 1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.1, < 2.0.0)
    roo-xls (1.0.0)
      nokogiri
      roo (>= 2.0.0beta1, < 3)
      spreadsheet (> 0.9.0)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.8)
    rubyzip (1.1.7)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    spreadsheet (1.0.5)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    spring (1.4.0)
    sprockets (2.12.4)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.3.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    therubyracer (0.12.2)
      libv8 (~> 3.16.14.0)
      ref
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.3)
      coffee-rails
    twitter-bootstrap-rails (3.2.0)
      actionpack (~> 4.1)
      execjs (~> 2.2)
      rails (~> 4.1)
      railties (~> 4.1)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.7.2)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.1)
    warden (1.2.4)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webrobots (0.1.2)
    will_paginate (3.0.7)
    will_paginate-bootstrap (1.0.1)
      will_paginate (>= 3.0.3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acl9 (~> 2.0)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  byebug
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  date_picker
  devise
  font-awesome-sass (~> 4.5.0)
  i18n_generators
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  jquery-rails
  jquery-turbolinks
  jquery-ui-rails
  less-rails
  libv8
  mysql2
  nokogiri
  paranoia (~> 2.0)
  puma
  rails (= 4.1.11)
  rails-jquery-autocomplete
  render_anywhere
  roo (~> 2.1.0)
  roo-xls
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  therubyracer
  turbolinks
  twitter-bootstrap-rails
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
  will_paginate (~> 3.0.6)
  will_paginate-bootstrap

BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.5
```

David